# Caracteres no Validos Vb6.0

Tags: vb6

Tengo un error en visual basic 6.0, dice Error caracteres no validos en ruta de acceso, les comparto el código para ver si alguien sabe a que se debe ese error.

```
 Call tim.procesaCfdi("C:\Entrada\aaaaaa.cer", "C:\Entrada\aaaaaaaaa.key", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxx@mail.com", "xxxxx", "C:\QR\", "C:\xmlsellar\", "C:\Entrada\", "C:\xmlout\", "C:\xmlerror\")
```

Comment: Cesar, lo que agregas en tu pregunta es exactamente como lo tienes en tu código o lo modificaste poniendo caracteres "x"? si lo modificaste, tal vez uno de esos caracteres tengan el problema pero no podríamos verlo...

Answer (score 1):

Revisa los parámetros de tu método `procesaCfdi()`, en lugar de recibir una ruta, donde se requiera, envías un texto o email, por esa razón el mensaje:

> Error Caracteres no validos en la ruta de acceso